# How to remove or add a class on checking or unchecking a checkbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

**Desired Behaviour**

On changing the checked status of a checkbox, I want to remove or add a class.

I have the functionality for the logic working, but am having trouble traversing and targeting a specific `li` and making style changes.

**HTML**

```
<div class="one">
    <div class="two">
        <p>31</p>
        <div class="three">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="checkboxG1" name="checkboxG1">
                            <label class="css-label" for="checkboxG1">area_01 - click me</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="four">
        <ul>
            <li class="area_01 common"></li>
            <li class="area_02 common"></li>
            <li class="area_03 common"></li>
            <li class="area_04 common"></li>
            <li class="area_05 common"></li>
            <li class="area_06 common"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

The following is my last attempt after a series of failed attempts using `next()`.

I'm either messing up my traversing, or I'm not using `removeClass()` correctly.

```
$("input.css-checkbox:checkbox").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        // remove a class
        //var myVar = $(this).next($("li.area_01"));
        var myVar = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".four").find("li.area_01");
        myVar.removeClass("common");
    } else if (!this.checked) {
        // add a class
        var myVar = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".four").find("li.area_01");
        myVar.addClass("common");
    }
});
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/fns87knc/

Update: I should add that there will be a number of lists with the same classes, and therefore I need to specifically target "the next instance of this class from where I am clicking".

Comment: Like [`$('.four li:first').toggleClass('area_01', this.checked);`](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/fns87knc/5/)?

Comment: Read your "update", can you add an example?

Comment: Use var myVar = $("div.four").find("li.area_01");

Comment: Where is the class `.04` in your HTML?

Comment: Thanks, fixed typo re: `04` and `four`.

Comment: You cannot access `div.four` from `tbody` through `find()` method

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find()` method after traversing to `div.one` using `parents()`.
But this way is little bit slow.

```js
$("input.css-checkbox:checkbox").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    // remove a class
    //var myVar = $(this).next($("li.area_01"));
    var myVar = $(this).parents(".one").find(".four").find("li.area_01");
    myVar.removeClass("common");
  } else if (!this.checked) {
    // add a class
    var myVar = $(this).parents(".one").find(".four").find("li.area_01");
    myVar.addClass("common");
  }
});

/* 

Desired Behaviour

On checking the checkbox, the first li's background should change to green.  

On unchecking the checkbox, the first li's background should change back to grey.  

*/
```

```css
.area_01,
.area_02,
.area_03,
.area_04,
.area_05,
.area_06 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
}
.area_01 {
  background: green;
}
.area_02 {
  background: cyan;
}
.area_03 {
  background: yellow;
}
.area_04 {
  background: fuchsia;
}
.area_05 {
  background: purple;
}
.area_06 {
  background: lime;
}
li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.area_01.common,
.area_02.common,
.area_03.common,
.area_04.common,
.area_05.common,
.area_06.common {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <p>31</p>
    <div class="three">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" id="checkboxG1" name="checkboxG1">
              <label class="css-label" for="checkboxG1">area_01 - click me</label>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="four">
    <ul>
      <li class="area_01 common"></li>
      <li class="area_02 common"></li>
      <li class="area_03 common"></li>
      <li class="area_04 common"></li>
      <li class="area_05 common"></li>
      <li class="area_06 common"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fns87knc/6/)

```
$("input.css-checkbox:checkbox").change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        console.log('checked');
        // remove a class
        //var myVar = $(this).next($("li.area_01"));
        var myVar = $(this).closest(".two").siblings('.four').find(".area_01");
        myVar.removeClass("common");
    } else if (!this.checked) {
        // add a class
        var myVar = $(this).closest(".two").siblings('.four').find(".area_01");
        myVar.addClass("common");
    }
});

/* 

Desired Behaviour

On checking the checkbox, the first li's background should change to green.  

On unchecking the checkbox, the first li's background should change back to grey.  

*/
```

Try like this.

I selected the parent div with class two using `closest()` then find the sibling using `siblings()` that contains the list which is class four then add/remove the class

Comment: You can use `toggleClass` like `$('.four li:first').toggleClass('area_01', this.checked);`. no need of `if...else` here

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a class to the *li* element, you can use the following steps

1.Add the following code to the JS file.This code will add 'common' class to the *li* element if the checkbox is checked otherwise will remove that class.

```
jQuery("input.css-checkbox:checkbox").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            jQuery('.four ul li').addClass('common');
        }
        else
        {
           jQuery('.four ul li').removeClass('common');
        }
    });
```

2.Write the following statement in your CSS file.

```
.common{
    background: red;
}
```

3. After doing this remove the 'common' class from the *li* element, since we will be adding or removing it dynamically.

To check this example please refer this link- http://jsfiddle.net/r4zokodb/